# jQuery MarginLeft Percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website where the left margin is constantly changing. I want to make the left margin a percentage of the page and not a pixel value. How do I do this?

```
$('#dialog_title_span').text("Create new Network Lists").css({marginLeft: 20});
```

This moves it 20 pixels, but when I do "20%" it breaks the code. How do I overcome this problem.

**Why I Need this**
I'm using a progress bar and I want text to move with the progress bar.

Comment: dont change css via jquery instead create a class and then add or remove it with jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    $('#dialog_title_span').text("Create new Network Lists").css({
      "margin-left": "20%"
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Curious - Why did you put "margin-left" in quotations? I tried it without the quotes before I asked the question and it didn't work. Why did you know to use them? Thanks

Comment: if do not have a variable called marginLeft how do you plan to use it? and again create a css class and use addClass and removeClass instead of using `.css`

Comment: @IdeoREX I would have to try it myself, but I don't think putting the margin part in quotes in necessary. what is necessary is putting the 20% in quotes, because when it tries to read it, the code doesn't see quotes, and tries to read it as a number, which it is not.

Comment: @DavidChase marginLeft is the same as margin-left to Jquery, it isn't a variable of his.

Comment: @user2532739 IMO if i do not have a variable defined i would put it in quotes so i use "margin-left" & "marginLeft" regardless of jQuery or not.

Comment: @DavidChase I guess we were both half right. From the API: "Notice that with the DOM notation, quotation marks around the property names are optional, but with CSS notation they're required due to the hyphen in the name." DOM notation being marginLeft, css notation being margin-left